# Python ordinary dictionary to ordered dictionary conversion

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary, ordereddictionary

I have python ordinary dictionary. In this, insertion order is not preserved. I need to keep elements in insertion order. I know that [`OrderedDict`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict) can do this job. but, my problem is i need to get an ordered dictionary from an already existing ordinary dictionary. This dictionary cannot be changed. Following is my ordinary dictionary:

```
d = {'tag': {'a': 1, 'c': {'k': 8}, 'b': 7, 'n': 6}}
```

Is there any way in python to keep order of elements in an already existing dictionary? Any help is appreciated. Using python 2.7

Comment: I don't get it. What order would you like your existing dictionary in? Whatever order you placed your items in, that order is already lost.

Comment: If ordinary dictionaries preserved the order, why would ordered dictionaries exist?

Comment: Since this is impossible, perhaps we are still able to help if you can explain why you think you need to do this?

Comment: See the accepted answer at:

[convert a dict to sorted dict in python][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13062300/convert-a-dict-to-sorted-dict-in-python

Answer (score 8):

Short Answer: This is not possible, once you have created the dictionary it has no order.

Items are stored according to their hash and not their insertion order, you need to have the `OrderedDict` created at the start so it can record insertion order as items are inserted.

Answer (score 0):

Okay lets get it straight.. theoretically it's not possible.

But just for laughs..

Since you yourself are looking at the shell output and figuring out the order (I'm assuming so since how else would you yourself know the order?) So here we go..

```
import re

d = {'tag': {'a': 1, 'b': 7, 'c': {'k': 8}, 'n': 6}}
tags = d['tag']
sorted_keys = set(re.findall(r"'(\w)':", str(tags))).intersection(tags.keys())

print sorted_keys  # You can form your OrderedDict
```