# Python: Create sorted list of keys moving one key to the head

Tags: python, sorting, dictionary, exception, key

Is there a more pythonic way of obtaining a sorted list of dictionary keys with one key moved to the head? So far I have this:

```
# create a unique list of keys headed by 'event' and followed by a sorted list.
# dfs is a dict of dataframes.
for k in (dict.fromkeys(['event']+sorted(dfs))):
    display(k,dfs[k]) # ideally this should be (k,v)
```

Comment: Do you want the keys and values? Use d.items().

Comment: PS: Don't name variables "dict" because that is the name of the class.

Comment: @KennyOstrom Look again.dict is being used as a class name.`dict.fromkeys` has the benefit of removing the duplicate `event` key.

Comment: ah got it, my bad

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you would be able to do

```
for k, v in list(dfs.items()) + [('event', None)]:
```

`.items()` casts a dictionary to a list of tuples (or technically a `dict_items`, which is why I have to cast it to list explicitly to append), to which you can append a second list. Iterating through a list of tuples allows for automatic unpacking (so you can do `k,v in list` instead of `tup in list`)

Comment: Good code. Change list to sorted. The new entry goes first. This doesn't remove the existing 'event', but that's probably a different question anyway (I would use filter).

Comment: Almost. Using @KennyOstrom suggestions, a remaining issue is that `event` is duplicated: `for k, v in [('event', dfs['event'])]+sorted(dfs.items()):
    display(k,v)`

Answer (score 0):

What we really want is an iterable, but that's not possible with sorted, because it must see all the keys before it knows what the first item should be.

Using dict.fromkeys to create a blank dictionary by insertion order was pretty clever, but relies on an implementation detail of the current version of python. (dict is fundamentally unordered) I admit, it took me a while to figure out that line.

Since the code you posted is just working with the keys, I suggest you focus on that. Taking up a few more lines for readability is a good thing, especially if we can hide it in a testable function:

```
def display_by_keys(dfs, priority_items=None):
    if not priority_items:
        priority_items = ['event']
    featured = {k for k in priority_items if k in dfs}
    others = {k for k in dfs.keys() if k not in featured}
    for key in list(featured) + sorted(others):
        display(key, dfs[key])
```

The potential downside is you must sort the keys every time. If you do this much more often than the data store changes, on a large data set, that's a potential concern.

Of course you wouldn't be displaying a really large result, but if it becomes a problem, then you'll want to store them in a collections.OrderedDict (https://stackoverflow.com/a/13062357/1766544) or find a sorteddict module.

```
from collections import OrderedDict

# sort once
ordered_dfs = OrderedDict.fromkeys(sorted(dfs.keys()))
ordered_dfs.move_to_end('event', last=False)
ordered_dfs.update(dfs)

# display as often as you need
for k, v in ordered_dfs.items():
    print (k, v)
```

If you display different fields first in different views, that's not a problem. Just sort all the fields normally, and use a function like the one above, without the sort.

Comment: Duplicates are not possible. dict.fromkeys() builds a dict which, by definition, never contains dups.

Comment: updated. Sorry I didn't read your original code correctly.